# Dlink Sharecenter & Mydlink cloud

Tags: nas, cloud, ddns

Hello I have just recently purchased a dlink dns-345 NAS, I've contacted dlink twice now and not a single reply so I'm hoping to get help here.

I was having problems setting the device up, even with the dlink disk it took me two Weeks to format and setup the raid with multiple resets; finally I was able to transfer my files, I'm able to map the drive but unable to find it browsing on my network with windows 7.  I'm also able to connect via internet and believe my Ports are all set correctly, I have also signed up for a free dlinkddns account which uses dyndns.

I'm unable however to connect my smartphone/tablet via the mydlinkcloud app in order to stream movies online; a process which dlink not only advertises as a selling feature for the nas but claims is fast and easy to setup.

I'm unable to log into the mycloud app as I don't have a user name (it's not the same as dlinkddns.com) I'm unable to set one up as they instruct on the website your 'device' will prompt you; but my nas has not done any such thing.

Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I got a response back from dlink and they gave me a link to download the addon pack for the cloud service; apparently it was supposed to be installed from factory buy missing on mine.